# Fixed Width File to 'Space' delimited in OS X

Tags: macos, delimited

Need to convert Fixed Width File to 'space' delimited in OS X. However, I need the delimiter to be any amount of spaces that are greater than one.

```
 Principal Position       Year      Salary       Bonus     Compensation(2)
-----------------------   ----    ----------   --------    ---------------
Sample Name here . . .    xxxx     $xxx,xxx       $x             $x
```

The required output would look similar to this; however, I've been using the following code and it is not working because a single space delimiter is not adequate:

```
Column -s $' ' example.txt
```

Is it possible to set my delimiter to any amount of spaces greater than 1? 
Thank you!

Comment: What are you DOING with this data? The best way to process your input might be selected by the most appropriate output for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to replace patterns with other text. For example:

```
$ sed 's/ \{2,\}/@/g' sample.txt
 Principal Position@Year@Salary@Bonus@Compensation(2)
-----------------------@----@----------@--------@---------------
Sample Name here . . .@xxxx@$xxx,xxx@$x@$x@
```

If you replace your multiple-space separators with spaces, though, you'll run into problems when the fields themselves contain spaces, as they do in your sample (both headers and data). Better to use some other delimiter.